# PHPMyAdmin with nginx in Docker proxy not working

Tags: nginx, php, docker

I have a docker setup with PHP/MySQL and PHPMyAdmin running on nginx webserver

I want to create a subdirectory on nginx `/phpmyadmin` which will proxy to the phpmyadmin container. Everything else should be served by php and nginx.

The problem: `/phpmyadmin` loads with the login screen, but nothing else. I can't login, because nginx shows 404 page

```
https://example.com/phpmyadmin/index.php?route=/ 404
```

The `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    image: php:7.3-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./data/src:/code

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 8085:80
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx/site.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./data/src:/code
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mysql
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=user

  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=db
      - PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI="https://example.com/phpmyadmin/"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

The `nginx.conf`:

```
worker_processes 4;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    server {
        listen 80;
        index index.php index.html;
        server_name localhost;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        root /code;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass web:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }

        location ~ \/phpmyadmin/ {
                rewrite ^/phpmyadmin(/.*)$ $1 break;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://phpmyadmin;
            }
    }
}
```

I have tried with `location /phpmyadmin/` that also did not worked. It seems like the `PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI` is not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one instead:

```
location ^~ /phpmyadmin/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://phpmyadmin/;
}
```

The `^~` will made this location to handle every URI starting with `/phpmyadmin/` **including** those that are finishing with the `.php` suffix. This one will also cut the `/phpmyadmin` prefix because of the trailing slash after the upstream name, and will do it more efficiently that using the `rewrite ... break` directive.

Keep your `PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI` to be set exactly as it is set right now.

Comment: Thanks, this is what made it working. The other location (.php) consumed all the requests, thats why it did not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that worked, here's my full config:
I'm using nginx, phpmyadmin and mysql default containers.

```
**default.conf**    
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name my.domain.here;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://container_phpmyadmin/;
        }
    }

**docker-compose.yml**
  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: container_mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_NAME}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - '../docker/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql'
    networks:
      - app-network
  
  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: container_phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
      - database
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: database
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 300M
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 0
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - database
    networks:
      - app-network
  

nginx:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: container_nginx
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ../docker/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:ro
      - ../docker/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - database
    networks:
      - app-network
```